# In Spring, How do Search and Use Library Correctly

Tags: spring

I usually coded in Node.js env.
So If I need some library, do Steps below

1. I search for google to get hint of library
2. Go npm, search that library
3. See docs to know how-to-use via github

In Spring, I don't know how people get info of how-to-use except 'spring.io'

what i know is

1. Search for google
2. In MVN Repository, I can search library with how-to-install

missing is
3. See docs to know how-to-use

How do people find and use Spring Library??

Comment: Just 1 as that will generally lead you to the homepage of the library which includes everything you need.